# Author Validation failed. Please make sure your git identity is correctly configured. Author and committer must match in firmwide Directory

Tags: bitbucket, git-commit

I am getting the issue mentioned in the title while I'm trying to push my files from my branch.

I have checked git config --list

User. Name and user. Email is correctly configured.

I have also tried

Git commit --amend --reset -author

This command also doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "Firmwide directory" is not a Git concept. It must be an add-on by your administrator, in GitLab or Bitbucket (which one are you using? it can't be both!).

Comment: Using bitbucket

Comment: I've trimmed the tags, but in general you'll have to find out what your administrator is demanding of your commits, that you aren't supplying.